# Can effective duration > modifed duration for a callable bond? I get that in QuantLib

Tags: quantlib, callable-bonds

I am using QuantLib to create a CallableFixedRateBond. I set up the HullWhite model as the pricing engine and compute effective duration and modified duration. Given the price of the bond is heavily discounted (thus unlikely to get called), my expectation is that EffDuration would be equal or perhaps slightly smaller than modified duration. It comes out higher. Here's the code:

```
# Create Callable Fixed Rate Bond

# Define the payment schedule
effective_date = ql.Date("2021-05-20","yyyy-mm-dd")
maturity_date = ql.Date("2029-06-01","yyyy-mm-dd")
first_coupon_date = ql.Date("2021-12-01","yyyy-mm-dd")
end_of_month = True
frequency = ql.Period('6M')
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond)
holiday_convention = ql.Unadjusted
date_generation_rule = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
schedule = ql.Schedule(effective_date, maturity_date, frequency, calendar, holiday_convention, holiday_convention, date_generation_rule, end_of_month, first_coupon_date)

# Define call schedule
call_schedule = ql.CallabilitySchedule()
calls = [
    ("2029-06-01", 100)
    ]
for entry in calls:
  call_schedule.append(ql.Callability(ql.BondPrice(entry[1], ql.BondPrice.Clean),ql.Callability.Call, ql.Date(entry[0],"yyyy-mm-dd")))

# Create the bond
settlement_days = 2
face_amount = 100
coupons = [0.04875]
daycount = ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.ISDA)
redemption = 100
callable_bond = ql.CallableFixedRateBond(settlement_days, face_amount, schedule, coupons, daycount, holiday_convention, redemption, effective_date, call_schedule)

# Create a flat curve, prep for bumping
base_curve = ql.FlatForward(2, ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond), 0.05, ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.ISDA))
bump = ql.RelinkableQuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0))
curve = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(base_curve), bump)
curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(curve)

# Create HW model
alpha = 0.03
sigma = 0.012
hw0 = ql.HullWhite(curve, alpha, sigma)

# Create Pricing Engine
settlement_date = ql.Date("2023-11-30","yyyy-mm-dd")
grid_steps = int((maturity_date - settlement_date) / 30)
engine = ql.TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine(hw0, grid_steps)
callable_bond.setPricingEngine(engine);

# Compute OAS
clean_price = 70.926
oas = callable_bond.OAS(clean_price, curve, daycount, ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, settlement_date)
print(f"OAS = {oas * 10_000:,.2f} bp")

# Compute Effective Duration using ql function
spread = 0.001
eff_dur = callable_bond.effectiveDuration(oas, curve, daycount, ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, spread)
print("\n*** Using QL function ***\n")
print(f"Eff Dur = {eff_dur:,.4f}")

# Compute mod duration
bond_yield = callable_bond.bondYield(clean_price, daycount, ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, settlement_date)
ir = ql.InterestRate(bond_yield, daycount, ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual)
mod_dur = ql.BondFunctions.duration(callable_bond, ir, ql.Duration.Modified )
print(f"Mod Dur = {mod_dur:,.4f}")
```

The results are:

`Eff Dur = 4.4045`
and
`Mod Dur = 4.3499`

A difference of `Mod Dur - Eff Dur = 0.0546`

Looking at the quantlib sourcecode I notice that Effective Duration is computed based on clean prices. When I manually compute it using dirty prices it comes closer to Mod Dur, but still a little higher:

```
# Manually compute Eff Dur using dirty price
accrued = callable_bond.accruedAmount(settlement_date)
base_price = callable_bond.cleanPriceOAS(oas, curve, daycount, ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, settlement_date) + accrued
up_price = callable_bond.cleanPriceOAS(oas + spread, curve, daycount, ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, settlement_date) + accrued
down_price = callable_bond.cleanPriceOAS(oas - spread, curve, daycount, ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual, settlement_date) + accrued
eff_dur = (down_price - up_price) / (2 * base_price * spread )
print("\n***Bumping OAS manually, using dirty price***\n")
print(f"Eff Dur = {eff_dur:,.4f}")
```

This gives:
`Eff Dur = 4.36629` and `Mod Dur = 4.3499`

A diff of `Mod Dur - Eff Dur = 0.0164`

So an improvement but still higher than Mod Duration. The difference seems small, is this justified by numerical approximation? Any suggestions or comments?

Comment: Answered in https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/1882